# NSFetchedResultsController and scrollToBottom in Table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I using **NSFetchedResultsController** with **UITableView**. I need to do a Chat like as iMessage, with ordered message from top to bottom. I need scroll to bottom my **UITableView** to show last message

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastMessageIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: false)
```

but when I scrolling my **UITableView**, it is then method **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:** calling for all messages in fetchedResultsController. I think that because of this, and there is a very long opening viewController

please help me solve this problem, and accelerate opening viewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't scroll, just set the content offset without animation. At minimum the height of each cell needs to be determined but the cell itself doesn't need to be loaded for every row.

Note that most apps which display in this way won't have all old messages in the immediate history, they'll only have a couple of pages, and if you scroll up too far they'll need to go and load those older messages. This approach bounds and loading issues.

Comment: can you post an example of how to do that?

Comment: @alionthego instead of that consider setting the transform of the table view and each and every cell so they're all upside down (so the bottom of the view just becomes the top)

Comment: thx @Wain, seems like a good solution but so many things get broken.  primarily the insets and the changes to offset when the keyboard is animated up and down.  I'll keep trying to piece it together.